# How to use field from subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT insent.id, notifications.id
FROM insent
WHERE insent.id IN (
    SELECT insent_id
    FROM notifications
)
;
```

But this gives an error saying:

> Unknown column 'notifications.id' in 'field list'

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get data from few tables in one query then you should use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) construction. For example:

```
SELECT 
    insent.id, 
    notifications.id 
FROM insent 
JOIN notifications ON notifications.insent_id = insent.id
```

if you don't want it you must remove `notifications.id` field from field list

```
SELECT 
   insent.id
FROM insent
WHERE insent.id IN (
    SELECT insent_id FROM notifications
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is notifications table is not in the scope 
Try like this

```
SELECT 
   i.id, 
   n.id 
FROM insent AS i
JOIN notifications AS n ON n.insent_id = insent.id
```