# How to convert this subquery into a join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I've got the following query, which works as expected:

```
SELECT insent.id, notifications.id
FROM insent
WHERE insent.id IN (
    SELECT insent_id
    FROM notifications
);
```

This works as expected, but I want to convert it to a query with a join. I can do this:

```
SELECT 
    insent.id, 
    notifications.id 
FROM insent 
JOIN notifications ON notifications.insent_id = insent.id
```

but since multiple notification records can exist for every insent record, this produces more results than with the first query/subquery combination.

Any idea how I can only show an insent records once if multiple notification records exist for it?

Comment: You can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use field from subquery in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501040/how-to-use-field-from-subquery-in-mysql)

Comment: Since you're joining on `id` the values from both tables will always be the same. What are you trying to accomplish by pulling both values? Or are you really interested in some other field from the `insent` table?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `distinct` to avoid `insent` duplicates

```
SELECT distinct
    insent.id
FROM insent 
JOIN notifications ON notifications.insent_id = insent.id
```

I believe the solution using `IN` is much better. The query optimizer will use a semi-join more likely like this.

```
SELECT insent.id
FROM insent
WHERE insent.id IN (
    SELECT insent_id
    FROM notifications
)
```

HOWEVER, it is not clear how the first query, you provide in your question, can work? You can not access an attribute nested in the IN construct subquery from the outside query.

Comment: Not sure this is what the person is looking for, they indicated there are multiple notifications per insent record

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    insent.id, 
    notifications.id 
FROM insent 
JOIN (select distinct id, insent_id from notifications)notifications ON notifications.insent_id = insent.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe Celko, the auther of SQL for Smarties, suggests that you use the IN predicate for just this reason. You don't want to use SELECT DISTINCT because it uses an inner cursor that slows things down on larger data sets and promotes bad design. You are literally trying to limit the insent results by what identifiers exist in another table. Your first query, using the IN predicate is the better query.

Comment: Note that in his first query, the OP is getting data from `notifications` table, which is not accessible being inside the `IN(..)` clause. So, he anyways needs to do a JOIN.

Comment: Good point, @MadhurBhaiya. In that situation, his book points out issues with normalization, but real-world data doesn't always go by the book ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT r.NotificationId,InsentId
FROM ( SELECT 
    insent.id AS InsentId, 
    notifications.id AS NotificationId,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( PARTITION BY  i.id ORDER BY i.Id ) AS rn
FROM insent i
JOIN notifications n ON n.insent_id = i.id ) as r
WHERE rn=1
```